# Setting a FormField value in a in ModelForm's Constructor

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an extra field in a Django ModelForm. It is a Boolean field and I want it to be set to true if another field, from the model is not null. How do I change the value of the field in the ModelForm's constructor as I don't want to create a ModelForm dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```
class ModelFormClass(forms.ModelForm):

    boolean_field = forms.BooleanField()

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        super(ModelFormClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk and not self.instance.field:
            self.fields['boolean_field'].initial = True
```